# What hand sewing needles are best for beading?

Tags: sewing

Is there a hand sewing needle that has the same diameter and eye size as a #10 Quilting Betweens needle but that is much longer?

Comment: Cindi, in which country do you buy your #10 Quilting needles? Some size systems are not well known abroad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For beading projects, the specific needles I have used are Size 10-13 Beading Needles. The longest one I have is 5.5 cm or just under 2 1/4 in. I had success  with these and used them to add extra beading into my wedding gown.

The specific brand I have is Sew-ology. On the back of the package it says, "Ideal for beadwork and sequins", so this is likely what you are looking for, although I am not familiar with the specific quilting needle you referenced.